# Monogame transparent image bleeding

Tags: c#, monogame

For some reason, when I draw an image using spritebatch, the transparency in my image causes it to bleed. Here's what the image in the files is:
[image]

And here's what is actually draws:

[image: The Bleeding Image]

Answer (score 1):

It's not MonoGame - it's something in your code - either the way you're opening your `SpriteBatch`, some scaling, color tinting - hard to say, as you didn't post any drawing code; but the image draws normally in MonoGame:
[image]

Here's a minimal `Draw` method that produces that image in MonoGame, presuming the `texture` is accessible and loaded in `LoadContent`:

```cs
protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
{
    GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.Black);
    spriteBatch.Begin();

    spriteBatch.Draw(texture, Vector2.Zero, Color.White);

    spriteBatch.End();
    base.Draw(gameTime);
}
```

Comment: Could using Front To Back sprite sorting be a problem or maybe the point filter?
`Drawing.Begin(SpriteSortMode.FrontToBack, samplerState: SamplerState.PointClamp);`

Comment: @SeaPeaMe `SpriteSortMode` is unlikely to be an issue, as it looks like in your original post there's only one sprite anyway - sort it whichever way, same result. `SamplerState.PointClamp` might be an issue - try without it - does the image render properly?